# How to connect Athena with Power BI using ODBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi, amazon-athena

How to connect AWS Athena with Power BI using ODBC.

I have installed 64 bit Simba Athena Connection.

I have added appropriate bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution",
                "athena:CancelQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetCatalogs",
                "athena:GetExecutionEngine",
                "athena:GetExecutionEngines",
                "athena:GetNamespace",
                "athena:GetNamespaces",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryExecutions",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "athena:GetTable",
                "athena:GetTables",
                "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
                "athena:RunQuery",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:StopQueryExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:CreateDatabase",
                "glue:DeleteDatabase",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "glue:DeleteTable",
                "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
                "glue:UpdateTable",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "glue:DeletePartition",
                "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                "glue:UpdatePartition",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "glue:BatchGetPartition"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But what would be the ODBC connection configuration for it to connect to Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Install AWS CLI from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html)
2. Once installed, open Command Prompt and give `aws2 configure`. Enter AWS Access and Secret Key for the user.
3. Install ODBC from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-odbc.html).
4. Create A bucket policy as JSON and attach it to User (replace `bucketname` with the bucket which has the data to be projected on Power BI):

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution",
                   "athena:CancelQueryExecution",
                   "athena:GetCatalogs",
                   "athena:GetExecutionEngine",
                   "athena:GetExecutionEngines",
                   "athena:GetNamespace",
                   "athena:GetNamespaces",
                   "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                   "athena:GetQueryExecutions",
                   "athena:GetQueryResults",
                   "athena:GetTable",
                   "athena:GetTables",
                   "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
                   "athena:RunQuery",
                   "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                   "athena:StopQueryExecution"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "*"
               ]
           },
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "glue:CreateDatabase",
                   "glue:DeleteDatabase",
                   "glue:GetDatabase",
                   "glue:GetDatabases",
                   "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                   "glue:CreateTable",
                   "glue:DeleteTable",
                   "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
                   "glue:UpdateTable",
                   "glue:GetTable",
                   "glue:GetTables",
                   "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                   "glue:CreatePartition",
                   "glue:DeletePartition",
                   "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                   "glue:UpdatePartition",
                   "glue:GetPartition",
                   "glue:GetPartitions",
                   "glue:BatchGetPartition"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "*"
               ]
           },
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                   "s3:GetObject",
                   "s3:ListBucket",
                   "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                   "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                   "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                   "s3:CreateBucket",
                   "s3:PutObject"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname*"
               ]
           }
       ] }
   ```
5. Create an S3 bucket in the same region for power BI to write logs (in the below example its `s3://athenanelogbucket`.
6. Enter the following in ODBC Athena simba connector in Control Panel -> Administrator tools -> ODBC -> Add

   [image]
7. Set authentication options as Default credentials:

   [image]

Click on Test. If successful then proceed to powerbi

8. And Get Data -> search for odbc -> select simba  Athena odbc connector -> click connect.
9. It will ask for username and password, enter the user credentials.