# Power BI with AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, amazon-athena, region

I have Amazon Athena (Simba Athena) on AWS and I need to connect with Power BI.
When attempting to connect I get the following error message:

> Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08001] [Simba][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[AwsRegion]}"

What further configuration steps do I have to follow?

- I tried to check the Region on AWS and the places I operate from.
- I activated Spain since this is the region I want to use primarily.

Here is where I revised my region and activated Spain:

[image: AWS Regions]

Comment: To me, the error message is saying that the ODBC connection needs to be configured with the AWS Region. This would need to be set in the ODBC configuration, _not_ in AWS. How have you configured the ODBC connection?

Comment: Thank you for your help John. I have follow this instructions. I have place the region from spain and save it. I don't know if is the correct place.

Comment: I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861085/how-to-connect-athena-with-power-bi-using-odbc?rq=2

Comment: Step 6 on the page you linked shows a field for "AWS Region". The code for Europe (Spain) would be `eu-south-2` -- is that what you entered?